# Can't seem to send an email through Google API (Python)

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I've gone through the official documentation, but I can't seem to send an email through the Google API:

```
import httplib2
import os


from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-quickstart.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatability with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print 'Storing credentials to ' + credential_path
    return credentials


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = 'ENTER RECIPIENTS EMAIL ADDRESS HERE'
  message['from'] = 'ENTTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE'
  message['subject'] = 'ENTER SUBJECT'
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}


def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

I get no error or anything. From looking at python, it seems that it's been executed. But when I check the account for the test email, there isn't one. Does anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Why not use `requests`? It's much more robust and easy to use than `httplib2`?

Comment: Requests could work. Only in the official documentation they've used httplib2: 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Being a complete noob, I think i'll stick to what the documentation says :P

Comment: OK. It's just `httplib2` seems like pain in the ass.

Comment: `httplib2` is not actually being used by this code, and that's because there is no "main" code that invokes the `get_credentials()`, `CreateMessage()`, or `SendMessage()` functions. Nothing will happen unless one or more of those functions is actually called.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that mhawke, could you provide an example as to how I would call "CreateMessage()"?? I already defined it.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, you do not invoke any of the functions that you defined. So for example

```
CreateMessage("youremail@gmail.com","someone@gmail.com","Testing","Hello World")
```

Also I would probably replace

```
message['to'] = 'ENTER RECIPIENTS EMAIL ADDRESS HERE'
message['from'] = 'ENTTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE'
message['subject'] = 'ENTER SUBJECT'
```

With

```
message['to'] = to
message['from'] = sender
message['subject'] = subject
```

Otherwise those parameters are not being used...

You could also define a 'main'

```
def main():
    message = CreateMessage("youremail@gmail.com","someone@gmail.com","Testing","Hello World")
    # Do something with the message
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried the CreateMessage to call the function, but I get the following error: NameError: global name 'MIMEText' is not defined. Is this a module I'm missing or do I need to define something??

Comment: MIMEText is from the email library so: "from email.mime.text import MIMEText" would need to be added to the import statements